# there is a problem with the txHash, Signature verification failed

Tags: solana-program, pda

Hello there is a problem with the txHash, it tells me that the signature is invalid can you help me please :

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Deposit<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed, 
        payer=buyer,
        space = 4 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 32
    )]
    pub claimer: Account<'info, Claimer>, //this turns to be a signer??

    #[account(mut)]
    pub master: Account<'info, Master>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub buyer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub referal: Account<'info, Claimer>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

And

```
        const claimer = await PublicKey.createWithSeed(
          wallet.publicKey, "claimer", PROGRAM_ID
        );
        const txHash = await program.methods.deposit(amount).accounts({
            claimer: claimer,
            master: masterAddress,
            buyer: wallet.publicKey,
            referal: new PublicKey("2MZY3b42NzbRjGyuALnkKJJ3NeFk2otXrMtzb9dBCQ7i"),
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        })
        .rpc();

        await confirmTx(txHash, connection);


/////////
export const confirmTx = async (txHash, connection) => {
  const blockhashInfo = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
  await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash: blockhashInfo.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: blockhashInfo.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: txHash,
  });
};
```

---

the error im getting now is: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

```
const deposit = async (amount) => {
    const [pda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from("claimer")],
      PROGRAM_ID
    );
    const txHash = await program.methods.deposit(new BN(100000)).accounts({
        claimer: pda,
        master: masterAddress,
        buyer: wallet.publicKey,
        referal: new PublicKey("2MZY3b42NzbRjGyuALnkKJJ3NeFk2otXrMtzb9dBCQ7i"),
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .rpc();

    await confirmTx(txHash, connection);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to how you're deriving the PDA for the `claim` account.

try this instead:

```
  const [pda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [wallet.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from("claimer")],
    PROGRAM_ID
  )
```

Comment: the error im getting now is: 

Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account